# Rails 5 ActionCable receive not called

Tags: websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have an ActionCable channel that is working well in terms of Subscribing and receiving data. Everything works, except the receive(data) method is not being called when messages are being sent down the channel. Does anyone know why?
My cable channel:

```
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def connect
  end

  def subscribed
    current_user = @authorized_user
    stream_for current_user
  end

  def receive(data)
    Rails.logger.error "received: #{data.inspect}"
    puts "received: #{data.inspect}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

When I call the broadcast_to method, my consumer correctly receives the message, this all works fine:

```
 MyChannel.broadcast_to User.find(4), "test"
```

But my receive(data) method is never called (can't see my logging anywhere). As far as the [Rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) goes, this should just work, but when I look at the [Cable channel methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Base.html), I can't see receive at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!
You can specify the Channel action you wish to hit within the Cable message itself. In my example, if I wished my data to hit the "receive" method, my cable message would look like this:

```
{
    "command": "message",
    "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"MyChannel\"}",
    "data": "{\"someinfo\":\"hello world this is a test\",\"action\":\"receive\"}"
}
```